# Combining date and time columns into dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm

Tags: r, date, as.date

New to R and R studio.
I have imported a dataset with the date and time in five seperate columns headed:
YYYY MM DD hh mm
How do I combine these into a single date column of the format dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm?

Dataset:

[image: See Image for what the dataset looks like]

Comment: Please provide an example of what your data looks likes?

Comment: You could use lubridate e.g. assuming that one column is the date and the other the time: library(lubridate); df <- data.frame(date = c("2017/01/03"), time = c("04:25")); ymd_hm(paste(df$date, df$time)). However, if you don't want the seconds then adjut it using format().

Comment: I have attached an image of the data set in the question. Sorry this did not upload the first time.

Comment: I don't know if lubridate will work as each element of the date is in a seperate column so there are 5 different columns?

Comment: Same principle. df <- data.frame(Y = "2017", m ="01", D = "03", H = "04", M ="25");
ymd_hm(paste(df$Y, df$m, df$D, df$H, df$M, sep ="")). You should provide a reproducible example tho. A pic is not useful

Comment: copy and paste a few rows of data in the future than a pic to help people trying to help you

Answer (score 2):

Based on the new information and questions asked by @LauraKate in the comment.

Answers below are done with packages `dplyr` and `ggplot2`:

```
df <- read.table("http://www.ndbc.noaa.gov/data/realtime2/51206.txt")
names(df) <- c("YYYY", "MM", "DD", "hh", "mm", "WD", "WSPD", "V1", "GST", "WVHT", "DPD", "APD", "MWD", "BARO", "ATMP", "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5")


df2 <- df %>% 
  unite(date, YYYY, MM, DD, sep="-") %>% 
  unite(time, hh, mm, sep=":") %>% 
  mutate(timestamp=paste(date, time) %>% 
           as.POSIXct(., format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")) %>% 
  select(timestamp, ATMP) 

ggplot(df2, aes(timestamp, ATMP)) + geom_line()
```

[image]

To get warning points when daily max temperature is above 26 degree (C)?

```
df3 <- df2 %>% 
    mutate(date=as.Date(timestamp) %>% as.POSIXct) %>% 
    group_by(date) %>% summarise(temp=max(ATMP)) %>% 
    mutate(warnings = ifelse(temp > 26, "red", "black"))

ggplot(df2, aes(timestamp, ATMP)) + 
    geom_line() + 
    geom_point(data=df3 %>% filter(warnings=="red"), aes(date, y=27.5), color="red")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I will have a go at reproducing that now. How do I go about getting a warning to print for the times/ dates when the temperature is above 26?

Comment: Why 26 deg? coral bleaching?

Comment: The temp that hurricanes and tropical cyclones can start to develop :)

Comment: The warning points are great by the way! But can R also print some sort of warning as well? Like a text warning with the time/date too?

Comment: Nope. Don't quite get what you are trying to ask. You could try subsetting the data based on your condition, and that's pretty straightforward (digest the codes already provided). If you're confused or insist on a  more dynamic way of presentation, ask another question please. There's already too many questions in the edits that are of no benefits to others who may be having similar issues.

Comment: Okay I will worry about that later. Im having trouble entering the first bit of code between df2 <- df %>%  and select and keep getting the error message - Error in df %>% unite(date, YYYY, MM, DD, sep = "-") %>% unite(time, hh,  : 
  could not find function "%>%"       What am I doing wrong?/ Not entering?

Comment: You would require `dplyr` and `tidyr` to make the data manipulation work. For the plors you would require `ggplot2`.

Comment: So it seems dplyr and tidyr are not available for my R version 3.4.0! Are there equivalent packages in this version?

Comment: `install.packages("tidyverse")` to install all the required packages.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer which uses lubridate package ( a great package for working with dates). You need to paste or concatenate the various columns in one, wipe away the whitespace, then use lubridate to convert it from string to date format. Note I useed dmy_hms function ( you can use other functions as needed from https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lubridate/vignettes/lubridate.html

```
> df=NULL
> df$H=10
> df$M=54
> df$S=27
> df$DD=12
> df$MM=06
> df$YYYY=2007
> df=as.data.frame(df)
> df
   H  M  S DD MM YYYY
1 10 54 27 12  6 2007
> attach(df)

> df$dat1=gsub(" ","",(paste(DD,"/",MM,"/",YYYY)))
> df
   H  M  S DD MM YYYY      dat1
1 10 54 27 12  6 2007 12/6/2007
> df$tim1=gsub(" ","",(paste(H,":",M,":",S)))
> df
   H  M  S DD MM YYYY      dat1     tim1
1 10 54 27 12  6 2007 12/6/2007 10:54:27



> df$dat2=paste(df$dat1,df$tim1)
> df
   H  M  S DD MM YYYY      dat1     tim1               dat2
1 10 54 27 12  6 2007 12/6/2007 10:54:27 12/6/2007 10:54:27
> str(df)
'data.frame':   1 obs. of  9 variables:
 $ H   : num 10
 $ M   : num 54
 $ S   : num 27
 $ DD  : num 12
 $ MM  : num 6
 $ YYYY: num 2007
 $ dat1: chr "12/6/2007"
 $ tim1: chr "10:54:27"
 $ dat2: chr "12/6/2007 10:54:27"
> library(lubridate)

Attaching package: ‘lubridate’

The following object is masked from ‘package:base’:

    date

> df$dat3=dmy_hms(df$dat2)
> str(df)
'data.frame':   1 obs. of  10 variables:
 $ H   : num 10
 $ M   : num 54
 $ S   : num 27
 $ DD  : num 12
 $ MM  : num 6
 $ YYYY: num 2007
 $ dat1: chr "12/6/2007"
 $ tim1: chr "10:54:27"
 $ dat2: chr "12/6/2007 10:54:27"
 $ dat3: POSIXct, format: "2007-06-12 10:54:27"
> df
   H  M  S DD MM YYYY      dat1     tim1               dat2                dat3
1 10 54 27 12  6 2007 12/6/2007 10:54:27 12/6/2007 10:54:27 2007-06-12 10:54:27
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I will have a go though am feeling very overwhelmed by this project. I'm very new to R and need to take the real time data from http://www.ndbc.noaa.gov/data/realtime2/51206.txt and create a plot with just the date against WTMP (temp) and possibly cut out the other columns if needed. I then need to put a linear line on the plot at 26 deg to show a max and then make r print a warning for when the temp is above 26 deg... Anyone want to help? Haha Any suggestions and tips?

Comment: make this another question

Comment: Adam Quek is helping me with it above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`lubridate::make_datetime`](http://lubridate.tidyverse.org/reference/make_datetime.html) for this.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df <- data_frame(
  YYYY = sample(2000:2017, 10),
  MM = sample(1:12, 10),
  DD = sample(1:28, 10),
  hh = sample(1:23, 10),
  mm = sample(1:59, 10)
)

mutate(df, 
  date_time = make_datetime(
    year = YYYY, month = MM, day = DD, hour = hh, min = mm
  )
)

#> # A tibble: 10 x 6
#>     YYYY    MM    DD    hh    mm           date_time
#>    <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>              <dttm>
#>  1  2007     8    11     4    27 2007-08-11 04:27:00
#>  2  2002     7     5    23    51 2002-07-05 23:51:00
#>  3  2006     2    25    12    45 2006-02-25 12:45:00
#>  4  2008    10     1     1     1 2008-10-01 01:01:00
#>  5  2000     1    28    10    42 2000-01-28 10:42:00
#>  6  2010     4    12    21    37 2010-04-12 21:37:00
#>  7  2013    12     8    16    58 2013-12-08 16:58:00
#>  8  2014     5    17    18    56 2014-05-17 18:56:00
#>  9  2009     9    27    20    36 2009-09-27 20:36:00
#> 10  2001     3    14    14    14 2001-03-14 14:14:00
```