# Import separate date and time (hh:mm) excel columns, to use for time elapsed calculation

Tags: r, excel, date, time, readxl

Newbie here, first post (please be gentle).  I have been trying to resolve this for several hours, so finally decided time to ask advice.

I have a large spreadsheet which I am importing with readxl.  It contains one column with date (format dd/mm/yyyy) and several time columns in format hh:mm as can be seen: [excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54ekO.png)

Essentially I want to be able to import both time and date columns and combine them, so that I can then do some other calculations, like time elapsed.

- If I import letting R guess the col-types, it converts the times to POSIXct, but these then have a date on 1899 attached to them: [R_POSIXct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Utekh.png)
- If I force readxl to assign the time column to numeric, I get a decimal (e.g. 0.315972222 for 07:35), which then tried converting using similar syntax to

  > format(as.POSIXct(Sys.Date() + 0.315972222), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz="UTC")

i.e.

> df$datetime <- format(as.POSIXct(df$date + df$time), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", tz="UTC")

which results in the correct date, but with a time of 00:00, not the time it is passed.

I have tried searching here and found posts to be not quite the same question (e.g. [Combining date and time columns into dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44319999/combining-date-and-time-columns-into-dd-mm-yyyy-hhmm)), and have read widely, including about about lubridate, but as I'm only 6 months into R, am finding some explanations a bit cryptic.

Suggestions or ignposting appreciated (if there are solutions I haven't found)

Comment: Excel holds its datetime values internally as decimal fraction of days since a reference date that was nominally 1900-01-01 but since they (the Lotus 1-2-3 authors and Microsoft Multiplan authors) both made the same leap year error it has remained in Excel. R follows the POSIX standard and stores its datetime values as decimal fractions of seconds since 1070-01-01.

Comment: You import with readxl, there are also `read.csv()`, `plyr`, `data.table` et al. implement their own readers, and some allow date conversion under the hood. See also `lubridate, fasttime` etc. Also, don't post a PNG image snippet of your data, post reproducible code giving a few rows.

Comment: To help others: - I found:  csv file saved in MacOS imports as "ddmmyy" format, but if csv file saved in Windows, imports as "ddmmyyyy".  My approach was unwise, adding exporting / interfacing problems (SQL->XLS (Win)->csv->Mac R->Windows R..).  This caused year 1929 to appear as 2029, but I didn't trace point(s) of error in process, as found another approach (direct SQL connection using RODBC imports dates as POSIXct.      Easily googled, but highlighting here
- Windows DateSystem has Day 1 as 01-Jan-1900
- Mac DateSystem has Day 1 as 02-Jan-1904
- R POSIXct has Day 1 as 01-Jan-1970

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you subtract the number of days between 1899-01-01 and 1970-01-01 and then multiply that (shifted) Excel numeric value by 3600 you should come close to the number of seconds since start of 1970. You could then convert to POSIXct with as.POSIXct( x, origin="1970-01-01"). That does seem to be "the hard way", however

It would be far easier and probably more accurate to convert the date-times to YYYY-MM-DD H:M:S format and then export as csv to be imported into R as text. There is a "POSIXct" colClasses argument to `read.csv`, although it doesn't handle separate columns of date and time. For that you would be advised to import as character values and then `paste` the dates and times. Then watch you format strings for as.POSIXct. The dd/mm/yyyy "format" would be  specified by "%d/%m/%Y".